# C# Wpf Button Activation

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a Wpf Socket

The messagebox is appers only when there is a problem with
the Ip address and port number.

After closing the messagebox I can't connected even I put proper Ip address and port number.
I have to restart the program to connect.
I like to try to re-connect by giving a new Ip address and prot number after without restrating the program

```
        if (socketWatch == null)
        {
            dicScoket = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();
            socketWatch = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,                                                      ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(txtIP.Text.Trim());
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, int.Parse(txtPort.Text.Trim()));
                socketWatch.Bind(endPoint);
                socketWatch.Listen(20);
                Listen();
                Showmsg("Connected!");
                
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            { 
            
                MessageBox.Show(" Error");
```

[image]

[image]

can't re-connect after closing messagebox

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be the `socketWatch` variable which is checked for being `null` before the connection attempt. The variable is initialized on the first attempt and remains not `null` ever after. Consider adding

```
socketWatch.Dispose();
socketWatch = null;
```

inside the `catch` block.

Comment: Thank you for your solution it's works perfectly, but I don't understand how this works, if you don't mind can you explain how this(functions?) work?

Comment: @C2C In the original code the `if (socketWatch == null)` condition and setting `socketWatch` inside the `if` block works like a latch, i.e. the block is only executed the first time when the `socketWatch` variable is `null`. On the second and consecutive calls the variable is already set so the condition is not fulfilled and the block, which includes socket connection, is not executed. The solution is to reset `socketWatch` each time the connection is unsuccessful to allow the `if` block to be executed again.